# How to resize control with rotated in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, rotation, resize

... I can't speak english...

I have a problem.
I want to resize after rotate using 8 ResizeThumb.(like PowerPoint)
But when I applied **RotateTransform**(orgin = 0.5), Resize method is strangely work.

Item ViewModel 
ViewModel has properties(X, Y, Angle, Width, Height) like this.

```
private double _X;
public double X 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return_X;
    }
    set
    {
        value = Math.Round(value);
        if(_X == value) { return; }
        _X = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("X");
    }
}
... and Y, Angle, Height, Width.
```

And I tried Binding like this.

- Angle is binding at **RotateTransform**.
- X, Y is binding at **Canvas.Left/Top** or **TranslateTransform**.

But both case strangely work.

So when I calculate X,Y after rotate, I think calculate angle together.

```
public void ResizeTopCenter(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Matrix m = Matrix.Identity;
    m.Rotate(Angle * Math.PI/180);
    Point rotated = m.Transform(new Point(e.HorizontalChanged, e.VerticalChange));

    // little bit different every direction.
    ViewModel.X += rotated.X;
    ViewModel.Y += rotated.Y;
    ViewModel.Height += rotated.Y;
}
```

Another way

```
Canvas.SetTop(this.designerItem, Canvas.GetTop(this.designerItem) + (this.transformOrigin.Y * deltaVertical * (1 - Math.Cos(-this.angle))));
Canvas.SetLeft(this.designerItem, Canvas.GetLeft(this.designerItem) - deltaVertical * this.transformOrigin.Y * Math.Sin(-this.angle));
```

...     strange as expected.

I can't write full source because I was off work.
Had suffered for eight hours, tomorrow is also continuing.

Please help me.

thank you.
and I'm sorry to read strage english.

Comment: what happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @MarkusHütter When I drag BottomCenter Thumb,  If the original source is set thie  **"- Height"**, and **"+ Y"**. When rotate control then,  CoordinatesSystem rotate together. so If only set **Y** and **Height** applies, it is the unintended locations.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to say. I see it's not easy for you but maybe try to formulate longer sentences, maybe I'll understand then. What exactly is the Problem? What is happening that shouldn't be happening?

Comment: Ok, I might be getting what your problem is. Something along the lines of "Order of transformation is messing things up". I don't have a solution for you though

Comment: @MarkusHütter  Thank you...